# Does the builder or villagers stoke the fire?

Tags: a-dark-room

My friend says that the builder or the villagers stoke the fire for you when it's flickering. Is this true?

Comment: Sorry, it said ADRÉ before because of a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: I don't think anyone does that for you. The stroke fire button is essentially a "save game" button, which only happens when you press it.

Comment: You can save like that? I tried that but it doesn't save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! The builder does, at least. I tested this in my own game:

> the fire is flickering.
>
> builder stokes the fire.
>
> the room is mild.

[image: shows the text ingame]

Comment: Thanks! It would be much easier now, that you can explore without risk of the fire dying out